# how to plot driving directions on google map api version 2 by using gps provider?

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-api-2

I am gone through the many websites..but i didn't get how to plot the driving directions on google map v2 by using gps provider.thanks in advance..
issues :
1.by using gps can't get accurate lat and long values..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030427/get-gps-navigation-location-in-a-fixed-interval-of-time-android/18030889#18030889) is a link where I have provided code snippets for fetching user's exact `Latitude` and `Longtitude`. Try it and share if you face anyother issues.

Look into [this](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822) for plotting driving directions on google map v2.

Hope these would help you